# Can "neither" be used with "nor"?

Tags: word-choice, conjunctions

I have the phrase

> You've entered neither a command nor a parameter.

Now I want to know is it correct or not? Can I use such combination as *neither–nor* in my case?

Comment: Yes you can. 'Neither' belongs with 'nor'.  'Either' belongs with 'or'.

Comment: [Neither a borrower nor a lender be,
For loan oft loses both itself and friend,
And borrowing dulls the edge of husbandry](http://www.enotes.com/shakespeare-quotes/neither-borrower-nor-lender) - William Shakespear.

Answer (score 10):

Absolutely! You not only *can*, but *should* use the pair.
In fact, this is the correct way of connecting two or more negative alternatives.

For more examples, see [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/neither-neither-nor-and-not-either) or definition 2.a [here](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/neither?showCookiePolicy=true).

Comment: Neither/nor is routinely given as the "opposite" of either/or: If you can do one or the other, you say either/or. If you can't do the one and you can't do the other, than it's neither/nor. "You can have either a banana or an apple." You can have a banana, or you can have an apple. "You can have neither a banana nor an apple." Sorry, you can't have either one. Maybe I'm eating them both.

Comment: "I can neither eat nor drink because I just went to the dentist" and "I can neither eat or drink because I just went to the dentist" are both used. And "Windows are to be closed if the outside temperature is low nor there is strong wind" is another use, tho probably mostly only recognized by tech-y people.